# Laravel 5, Unable to Find Object in Cache, using 'database' driver

Tags: php, laravel-5, caching

I am maintaining an old Laravel 5 application and trying to stand it up in the cloud, as our old servers are dying.

I am currently testing this in AWS, and am experiencing an issue with part of it due it failing to retrieve an object from the cache.

**.env** Set up

```
CACHE_DRIVER=database
CACHE_PREFIX=examplecache
```

**Code in Question**

```
if (! $res = Cache::get($this->getStoreKey()))
{
    throw new \ObjectNotFoundException('Can not find the object stored');
}
```

**Log file entry**

```
[2019-11-11 16:23:11] development.ERROR: exception 'ObjectNotFoundException' with message 'Can not find the object stored' in /home/forge/workers.mydomain.com/app/Queue/Jobs/MonitoredQueueJob.php:130
```

**Key it is looking for**

```
.monitoredqueuejob.getstorekey.102.4061b5c9fd5d912c3a04f2f55da329a03a12fa7e
```

**DB Extract where key exists**

```
"examplecache.monitoredqueuejob.getstorekey.102.4061b5c9fd5d912c3a04f2f55da329a03a12fa7e"   "eyJpdiI6Imo2aXZcL3RFNGlpcFZLT0VTNzA1dVpnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IkNlOU9RcHc5d3VWMlZcL1VGUmZtQVdnPT0iLCJtYWMiOiJiZDg5N2Q3MzQ1ODZlNjBjMGEzYTAwM2MzNjUyNGE0MjBiMzc2NzM2Mzk2NDU2NTg0YmM5NjBlODkwY2Q4M2FkIn0="  "1574094191"
```

What would prevent it from finding this object in the DB?

If I do this all via `php artisan tinker`  it finds the Object without issue.

Comment: Starting with the basics, is the AWS environment correctly setting the CACHE_DRIVER and CACHE_PREFIX values? The fact you can make it work via tinker makes me thing it's a difference between dev and prod.

Comment: Hi Chris, at the moment I only have the one dev environment, so the issue is happening on the same application where I also successfully complete the task with tinker.